# I do not see Spark Controller for Vora in SAP software Download page

Tags: apache-spark, vora

As per SAP VORA troubleshooting page:

Download: SAP customers can download the software on the SAP Support Portal

**Spark Controller**: Installations and Upgrades -> A-Z -> H -> SAP HANA PLATFORM EDITION -> SAP HANA PLATFORM EDIT. 1.0 -> Entry by Component -> HANA SPARK Controller

[SAP HANA VORA 1 (SUPPORT PACKAGES AND PATCHES)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1rQk.jpg)

But I do not see any Spark Controller download in SAP download page. Is the download location changed for Spark Controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your screenshot shows the Vora Downloads (under 'V'). The Spark Controller is part of HANA. You need to follow the path that you pasted in your question - under 'H' (Installations and Upgrades -> A-Z -> H -> SAP HANA PLATFORM EDITION -> SAP HANA PLATFORM EDIT. 1.0 -> Entry by Component -> HANA SPARK Controller).